# Trying to create ModMail using discord.py but I ran into Syntax Error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, syntax-error

I am creating a Discord Bot similar to ModMail but I ran into an error while I was coding.
Code:

```
   ​@bot.event
   ​async def on_message(message):
       ​if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
           ​return
   ​
       ​if message.author != message.author.bot:
           ​if not message.guild:
               ​embed= discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.blue())
               ​embed.add_field(name="AOS ModMail Support",
               ​value= (f"User Mention: {message.author.mention}\nUsername: {message.author}\nUser ID: {message.author.id}\n\n**Content**: {message.content}")
               ​await bot.get_guild(1111111111).get_channel(312312312324).
               ​send(embed=embed)
```

When I am DMing the bot my terminal looks like this:

```
await client.get_guild(832146513270145075).get_channel(841562259657850880).
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This is the part when I DM the bot and bot will convey the message to the given channel

Comment: `client` error message but you built in `bot`? I do not get it...

Comment: I know that I changed it earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do something like:

```py
​await bot.get_guild(1111111111).get_channel(312312312324).
               ​send(embed=embed)
```

If you want to get it to work put it all in one line

```py
​await bot.get_guild(1111111111).get_channel(312312312324).send(embed=embed)
```

But this is not really good practice, you should get the guild/channel and send the message in separate lines

```py
guild = bot.get_guild(...)
channel = guild.get_channel(...)
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

You can also use `bot.get_channel` for a shorter code

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(...)
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

*PS: If you really want it split into two lines like in your approach, you should use the backslash `\`*:

```py
​await bot.get_guild(1111111111).get_channel(312312312324) \
    .send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thanks, You helped me once again :)

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped